# Prompt message box through custom menu on Google Sheets/App Script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a custom menu on Google Sheets with two options:

```
function onOpen(e) {
 var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom')
 menu.addItem('Add new store', 'openForm')
 menu.addItem('Update Database', 'replacebackenddatabase') }
```

When a user selects "Update Database" I would like a message box to appear and ask for confirmation with "Do you want to proceed" and Yes/No basis. IF the user selects "Yes", I would like the function 'replacebackenddatabase' to run. If not, I would just like the message box to close and nothing to happen.

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Prompt boxes here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs).

```js
function replacebackenddatabase() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Ask a question...',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Get the response...
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    //If they clicked OK do something with 'text' variable

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // If they clicked Cancel.

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // If they closed the prompt

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOpen(e) {
 var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom')
 menu.addItem('Add new store', 'openForm')
 menu.addItem('Update Database', 'checkResponse')
 //.addSeparator()
 //.addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Sub Menu')
 //.addItem('One sub-menu item', 'subFunction1')
 //.addItem('Another sub-menu item', 'subFunction2'))
 .addToUi(); 

// do not set a variable to any chain of methods ending in .addToUi()
// after the Menu is created, the value of menu will be undefined
// the .addToUi() method does not return anything.

 }


function checkResponse() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to proceed?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    replacebackenddatabase();
  } else {
    Logger.log("The user wasn't sure.");
  }

}
```